# Logstash multiline filter fragments logs

Tags: filter, multiline, logstash

I'm trying to use the multiline filer to combine a fairly long java exception stack trace along with the main log message. I'm using the example shown here https://gist.github.com/smougenot/3182192

Following is my code:

```
input{
    stdin{}
}
filter{
    multiline {
                pattern => "(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)"
                what => "previous"
            }
}
```

However, instead of combining the stacktrace into one event, it is automatically fragmented into multiple different logs.

I can't seem to understand why? I have tried using codec instead of filter, yet the problem exists.

Comment: From my experience, stdin does not work well for this kind of test because it has its own buffer. And Logstash also has a buffer that it does not keep open forever since it has to output to ES as often as possible. As a consequence if two events that should have been grouped come as a too big interval they will be processed as two separate events